# Filtering columns by month pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe where the columns are datetime variables with the format of year-mm-dd.

I would like to filter the dataframe such that I only have the columns for a specific month. I have searched all over the forum and can't find anyone dealing with columns as datetime, only indices.

Best,

Comment: Can you add some data sample and expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with `loc`:

```
df = df.loc[:, df.columns.month == 1]
```

**Sample**:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2017-01-03', periods=5, freq='3M')
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(5)}, index=rng).T
print (df)
   2017-01-31  2017-04-30  2017-07-31  2017-10-31  2018-01-31
a           0           1           2           3           4

df = df.loc[:, df.columns.month == 1]
print (df)
   2017-01-31  2018-01-31
a           0           4
```

Comment: Brilliant answer!